# How to set/update values of my preferences (PreferencesAcitivity)?Android

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have a SettingsActivity ( extends PreferenceActivity ) , which is loaded from a preferences.xml file(res-->xml-->preferences.xml).

The preferences.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Patient&apos;s Settings" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Not Set"
        android:key="patientMobile"
        android:title="mobile number" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Doctor&apos;s Settings" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Not Set"
        android:key="docEmail"
        android:title="e-mail" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Not Set"
        android:key="docMobile"
        android:title="mobile number" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Application Settings" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:disableDependentsState="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="lang"
        android:summaryOff="English"
        android:summaryOn="Greek"
        android:switchTextOff="EN"
        android:switchTextOn="GR" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

How i can set/update/overwrite these values from another activity?

I retreive information from a webservice and then i want to save these values and then to be seen from SettingsActivity:

```
1.patientMobile (string)
2.docEmail      (string)
3.docMobile     (string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read/set/update these values using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and the key to the preference.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String patientMobile = preferences.getString("patientMobile");

//or set the values. 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("patientMobile", "yes"); //This is just an example, you could also put boolean, long, int or floats
editor.commit();
```

Comment: If i am at MainActivity(My menu), how i do that.as context i put SettingsActivity.class,like:                             SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.class)?

Comment: And another question,if patientMobile exists it overwrites it and if it dont exists it creates it?

Comment: You need to pass `this` for context if you are in `SettingsActivity` (or any `Activity` or `Service` class, they both inherit from `Context`). As for your second question, the answer is yes!

Comment: I am not at SettingsActivity but i want to overwrite some values from MainActivity!So?What i put as parameter?

Comment: As I said, any `Activity` class is fine. Your MainActivity extends `Activity` right?

Comment: Noooooooo!!! Use `this`. A reference to the Activity which extends Context. Like this:  `SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve values you save them like:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("patientMobile", patientMobile);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    editor.apply();
} else {
    editor.commit();
}
```

To read values simply call `sp.getString("patientMobile", defaultValue);`

See [apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29). Also [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) docs.